# Calculate total seconds on datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

I'm trying to sum total seconds from my datetime field. But problem is my data is like

```
2017-03-20 13:30:00
2017-03-20 13:30:24
2017-03-20 13:30:38
2017-03-20 13:32:46
2017-03-20 13:32:58
2017-03-20 13:33:06
2017-03-20 13:33:19
2017-03-20 13:33:27
2017-03-20 13:33:39
2017-03-20 13:33:53
2017-03-20 13:34:05
2017-03-20 13:34:13
2017-03-20 13:34:17
2017-03-20 13:34:25
2017-03-20 13:34:29
2017-03-20 13:39:38
2017-03-20 13:40:50
2017-03-20 14:35:00
```

with theese data's I'm just trying to get total seconds.

I tried

```
select (to_seconds(max(timeColumn)) - to_seconds(min(timeColumn))) / 60 as minutes
from times
```

And its not giving true data

Comment: Create a demo here of your problem and post a link in your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865726 Edited!

Comment: what u want sum or different ? because you are saying something and write query is different

Comment: I'm just trying to sum .

Comment: @MuratKaya have check my ans ?

Comment: @MuratKaya What is the desired result?

Comment: approximately 3 minutes. @Devart

Comment: Why 3 minutes, what is the formula to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

As your heading

```
  select sum(SECOND(timeColumn))/60 minutes from times
```

Comment: I checked your answer but it's giving a hilarious result. For example I sum by hand its 109 seconds but its giving 4.152,0333 minutes @knwoledge

Comment: give me what date have you used I will check and let you know

Comment: Actually I used data which I gave in sqlfiddle

 
sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865726

Comment: on which date ? there are there

Comment: locationDate is column which I'm trying to calculate . 2017-03-20 13:30:00

Comment: I have run on locationDate  like this  select sum(SECOND(locationDate))/60 minutes from location  it is give 5.05  and it is perfect result. I have cross verify

Comment: for this date it is  a 0.00 check it SELECT sum( SECOND( '2017-03-20 13:30:00' ) ) /60 minutes